# cakephp tableHeaders and width

Tags: cakephp

why i get th cell name "Array" ?
How set table th width?

```
   $th = array(         array(array(null),
    array('width'=>'80'))   ); 
echo $this->Html->tableHeaders($th);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're using the method correctly.

The proper usage for tableHeaders() is tableHeaders($tableHeaders, $trOptions, $thOptions);

The $trOptions and $thOptions should be arrays where you set the options for the HTML elements.

So to set the th width as you're trying to do above you'd have to do something like this:

```
$th = array('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3');
$trOptions = array();
$thOptions = array('width' => 80);
echo $this->Html->tableHeaders($th, $trOptions, $thOptions);
```

The th options array has to be the third argument so you have to include $trOptions as the second even if it's just an empty array.

All this info is actually explained quite well in the CakePHP documentation and API, so I'd encourage you to check there as well if you haven't already.

Here's info on $Html->tableHeaders in the documentation:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1446/tableHeaders

Here's the entry for $Html->tableHeaders in the CakePHP API:
http://api.cakephp.org/class/html-helper#method-HtmlHelpertableHeaders

Comment: Thanks, but i need set width only one <th> cell.

Comment: In that case you're probably going to have to do it the old fashioned way using plain HTML. I don't think CakePHP has anything to offer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I've submit this enhancement to cakephp core. It'll be available at 2.2.0
See [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/674) and [here](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2787-this-html-tableheaders-doesnt-support-column-specific-html-options-eg-class#ticket-2787-7).

So, this

```
echo $this->Html->tableHeaders(array(
        array('Name' => array('class' => 'column-name')),
        'Value'
    )
);
```

...will print this

```
<tr>
    <th class="column-name">Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
</tr>
```