# Changing table headers in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to change table settings (specifically the headers) in cakephp but I can't seem to get anything to work.

I tried using the advice from this post, but any changes I make aren't reflected in my table.
[cakephp tableHeaders and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712068/cakephp-tableheaders-and-width)

All I'm trying to do is print table headers and be able to adjust the width. No matter what I change the width to it won't work. I tried putting it as a class in the css file, and then call that class but nothing changes.

```
<?
$trOptions = array();
$thOptions = array('width'=>200);
echo $this->Html->tableHeaders(array('Date', 'Title', 'Active'),$trOptions, $thOptions);
?>
```

Comment: `<tr class="header_row"><th>Date</th><th>Title</th><th>Active</th></tr>`, css: `.header_row th { width: 200px; }`

Comment: Tried this and it's not working.

Comment: Then it's not a cakephp issue, try adding the !important flag to width rule.

Answer (score 0):

If, for whatever reason, you'd want to do this the CakePHP way:
`$this->Html->tableHeaders( array('Date', 'Title', 'Active'), array('class' => 'header_row'));`

Then your CSS should be `.header_row th { width: 200px; }` in your stylesheet.
And seriously, don't use CakePHP...

Comment: Why don't you like cakephp? I know people hate on PHP in general, but why is cake bad?

Comment: I love PHP, but CakePHP is an __awful__ framework. It's tightly coupled, overuses static methods, and has numerous other issues.

Comment: I use PHP quite a bit and figured I'd give cake a go. Do you not like any of the php frameworks?

Comment: Symfony2 is the best in my humble opinion, but many would say that no framework is good. I'd suggest you read [this blogpost](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/07/framework-fixation-anti-pattern.html).

Comment: Saying that "symfony2 is the best" is like praising the smartest kid in remedial class.

Comment: He might graduate when he turns 3.

Comment: @user1406951 , CakePHP is bad because it has : global state, static calls everywhere, error suppression, mis-implemented MVC and many other issues. Have you actually read Cake's source?

Comment: I appreciate your advice and input. I'd like to make a small project with cake and see how I feel. Anyway, I tried what you said for the tables and it didn't change the width.